# GC settings when running two or more JAVA applications

Tags: java-8, garbage-collection, jvm

We have a 20-core CPU running on a KVM (CentOS 7.8)
We have two heavy enterprise JAVA applications (Java 8) running on the same node.
We are using ParallelGC in both and by default 14 GC threads are showing up (default no. determined using ~ 5/8 * no. of cores)

Is it okay to have GC threads(combined is 14+14 = 28) exceeding the no. of cores(20) in the system ? Will there be no issues when GC threads on both JVM instances are running concurrently?

Would it make sense to reduce the no. of GC threads to 10 each ?
How can we determine the minimum no. of GC threads (ParallelGC) needed to get the job done without impacting for an application?

Answer (score 0):

> Will there be no issues when GC threads on both JVM instances are running concurrently?

Well, if both JVMs are running the GC at the same time, then their respective GC runs may take longer because there are fewer physical cores available.  However, the OS should (roughly speaking) give both JVMs an equal share of the available CPU.  So nothing should *break*.

> Would it make sense to reduce the no. of GC threads to 10 each ?

That would mean that if two JVMs were running the GC simultaneously then they wouldn't be competing for CPU.

But the flip-side is that a since a JVM has 10 threads for GC, its GC runs will always take longer than if it has 16 threads ... and 16 cores are currently available.

Bear in mind that *most of the time* you would expect that the JVMs are not GC'ing at the same time.  (If they are, then probably something else is wrong<sup>1</sup>.)

> How can we determine the minimum no. of GC threads (ParallelGC) needed to get the job done without impacting for an application?

By a process of trial and error:

- Pick an initial setting
- Measure performance with a indicative benchmark workload
- Adjust setting
- Repeat ... until you have determined the best settings.

But beware that if your actual workload doesn't match your benchmark, your settings maybe "off".

---

My advice would be that if you have two CPU intensive, performance critical applications, and you suspect that they are competing for resources, you should try to run them on different (dedicated!) compute nodes.

There is only so much you can achieve by "fiddling with the tuning knobs".

---

<sup>1 - Maybe the applications have memory leaks.  Maybe they need to be profiled to look for major CPU hotspots.  Maybe you don't have enough RAM and the real competition is for physical RAM pages and swap device bandwidth (during GC) rather than CPU.</sup>